# Restricting database in Postgresql

Tags: django, database, postgresql, pgadmin, hstore

I am using Django1.9 with Postgresql. This is my data model for the model "Feature" :

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    image_component = models.ForeignKey('Image_Component',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    feature_value = HStoreField()

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if Feature.objects.filter(feature_value__has_keys=['size', 'quality' , 'format']):
            super(Feature, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("Incorrect key entered")
```

I am imposing a restriction on the feature_value such that only the keys that is allowed with Hstore are **size** , **format** and **quality.** I can do this while updating the database using Django-Admin. But I am not able to update the database directly using pgAdmin3 with the same restrictions i.e , I want to impose the same restrictions on the database level. How can I do that? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [ALTER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) you `Future` table and add a [constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html) for `feature_value` field with such query:

```
ALTER TABLE your_feature_table
ADD CONSTRAINT restricted_keys
CHECK (
  -- Check that 'feature_value' contains all specified keys
  feature_value::hstore ?& ARRAY['size', 'format', 'quality']
  AND
  -- and that number of keys is three
  array_length(akeys(feature_value), 1) = 3
);
```

This will ensure that every data in `feature_value` could contain exactly three keys: size, format and quality; and won't allow empty data.

Note, that before applying this query, you need to remove all invalid data from the table, or you would receive an error:

```
ERROR: check constraint "restricted_keys" is violated by some row
```

You could execute this query in DB console, or since you're using Django, it would be more appropriate to create a migration and apply this query using [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql): create an emtpy migration and pass above query into `migrations.RunSQL`, and pass this query into `reverse_sql` param for removing the constraint when the migration is unapplied:

```
ALTER TABLE your_feature_table
DROP CONSTRAINT restricted_keys;
```

After applying:

```
sql> INSERT INTO your_feature_table (feature_value) VALUES ('size => 124, quality => great, format => A4')
1 row affected in 18ms

sql> INSERT INTO your_feature_table (feature_value) VALUES ('format => A4')
ERROR: new row for relation "your_feature_table" violates check constraint "restricted_keys"
Detail: Failing row contains ("format"=>"A4").

sql> INSERT INTO your_feature_table (feature_value) VALUES ('')
ERROR: new row for relation "your_feature_table" violates check constraint "restricted_keys"
Detail: Failing row contains ().

sql> INSERT INTO your_feature_table (feature_value) VALUES ('a => 124, b => great, c => A4')
ERROR: new row for relation "your_feature_table" violates check constraint "restricted_keys"
Detail: Failing row contains ("a"=>"124", "b"=>"great", "c"=>"A4").

sql> INSERT INTO your_feature_table (feature_value) VALUES ('size => 124, quality => great, format => A4, incorrect_key => error')
ERROR: new row for relation "your_feature_table" violates check constraint "restricted_keys"
Detail: Failing row contains ("size"=>"124", "format"=>"A4", "quality"=>"great", "incorrect_ke...).
```